# Receiving the dllNotFound error while executing the C# Solution in linux/mac/docker environment - kernel32.dll

Tags: docker, .net-core, sdk, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection

Need to containerize the Solution Build on Microsoft Information Protection SDK 1.6 in linux Container Architecture. Always receiving common error of dllNotFound.

Error Received while executing MIP Initialization: `MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);`

```
Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.UnsafeKernel32NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String dllToLoad)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls(String dllFolder, String dllName, String[] dllDependencies)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize(MipComponent mipComponent, String path)
   at MIPSolution.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Program.cs:line 55
```

**Dockerfile to Execute the Application:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \
        libc6-dev \
        libgdiplus \
        libx11-dev \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MIPSolution.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "MIPSolution.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "MIPSolution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MIPSolution.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
# RUN dotnet --info
RUN echo "Build number: $buildno"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MIPSolution.dll"]
```

All suggestions to make this application working will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: kernel32.dll is a part of the Windows operating system. It's not available on the Linux/Mac environment.

Comment: @KenWhite is there a way around to pull it and use it in non-windows environment

Comment: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime` will carry the Microsoft kernel, to execute the application in Linux/non-Windows environment

Comment: if kernal32.dll is only the part of windows os and cant be used in other OS, then how  **mono** or **wine** are able to execute same application/files in non-windows OS

Comment: I'm removing my previous comment, I think it's misleading and probably confusing terms.  The supported OS SDK in the MIP documentation references to Debian9, where as Debian10 is used for buster images.  I don't see references to dotnetcore 3.1 support for Debian9.